# Prove Rao-Cramer from scratch

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to prove Rao-Cramer lower bound from scratch. Here's my attemption:

It suffice to consider single sample case: $X$ sampled from distribution with p.d.f $p(x;\theta)$. And $f$ is an estimator with

$$\int f(x) p(x;\theta) dx=\theta$$

holds for every $\theta$.

And w.l.o.g again we consider the case $\theta=0$, namely we need to minimize

$$\int f^2(x) p(x;0) dx$$.

this looks like a harmless quadratic programming problem with linear constrains. So we have lagrangian
$$L=\int f^2(x) p(x;0) dx-\int\lambda(\theta)(\int f(x) p(x;\theta) dx-\theta)d\theta$$.

Differentiating against $f$ and $\lambda$ we have:

$$2f(x)p(x;0)=\int\lambda(\theta)p(x;\theta)d\theta$$
for every $x$ and
$$\int f(x) p(x;\theta) dx=\theta$$
for every $\theta$,
then I got stuck here, is it possible to get Rao-Cramer bound following this strategy? And do we always have Rao-Cramer bound euqal to the optimum for the proposed optimization problem?